# Using greater than logical expression in rendered attribute

Tags: jsf

I have an `outputText` field for which I write a condition in the `rendered` attribute. The condition is for comparing the length of the string with some numeric value.

```
<h:outputText id="emailaddress" 
    value ="#{subsAlertsHelper.personEmail.substring(0,20)}"
    rendered="#{subsAlertsHelper.personEmail.length() >20}" />
```

If I use `==` or `!=` in `rendered` it is working fine. But for greaterthan and lessthan it is not giving the output. What could be the reason for that?

Answer (score 51):

You have to use `gt` and `lt` operators.

Check out [JavaServer Faces Expression Language Intro](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html) from Sun/Oracle. Precisely the Operators section.

Comment: Indeed, the reason is that `<` and `>` are special characters in XHTML. When you have used JSP, this would have worked.

Comment: What is the operator for greater than equal to

Comment: @Ganesh It's `ge`. Check out the link from the answer, especially the chapter _Operators_.

Answer (score 3):

`rendered` only accepts EL expression.

`subsAlertsHelper.personEmail.length()` is incorrect.

On the personEmail object, add a method `getLength()` witch returns the length

```
public int getLength(){ return this. length();}
```

Modify :

```
rendered="#{subsAlertsHelper.personEmail.length >20}"
```

Comment: Also try gt 
rendered="#{subsAlertsHelper.personEmail.length gt 20}"

Comment: Keep yourself up to date. Read on about EL 2.2 which was introduced with Servlet 3.0 around Dec 2009. Invoking non-getter methods directly is allowed since EL 2.2, also with arguments.

Comment: I currently only use JSF 1.2 and never have to work with EL 2.2. You're right. Sorry for this answer... My comment is probably most appropriate (about the use of gt).